# How Can I enable FTS5 support in SQLite.swift using the Swift Package Manager

Tags: swift-package-manager, sqlite.swift

I have a project that is built using SPM and in it I use the SQLite.swift library ([src](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift)). In my `Package.swift` file I have the following dependency:

```
let package = Package(
...
  dependencies: [
    .package(url: "https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git", from: "0.14.1")
  ],
...
)
```

As per the documentation, however by default SQLite.swift only uses

> the most recent version of SQLite without any extras

There is a [CocoaPods example](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#cocoapods) of adding FTS5 support but I can't find anyone who is using this with SPM, is there an official way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the answer here - it explains why the vanilla SPM install does not add these extras: [How to enable FTS5 in GRDB.swift using SPM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74960462/how-to-enable-fts5-in-grdb-swift-using-spm)